# R: change round brace interval number by subtracting 1 from the value

Tags: r, dataframe, gsub, brackets

I have a data which is like this:

```
abc <- data.frame( a = c("[100-150)", "[150, 200)"))
```

I want to alter it to make it like this:

```
abc <- data.frame(a = c("100-149", "150-199"))
```

I know how to replace the brackets:

```
abc$a <- lapply(abc$a, gsub, pattern = "[", replacement = "", fixed = TRUE)
abc$a <- lapply(abc$a, gsub, pattern = "]", replacement = "", fixed = TRUE)
abc$a <- lapply(abc$a, gsub, pattern = ")", replacement = "", fixed = TRUE)
```

It is the subtraction of 1 number from the end that is the problem.

Is there a way to do this?

Please note this is just an example, in reality my data has a column like this which is about 2000 rows.

Comment: You should have used `sapply`. Turning your dataframe  columns into lists will trip you up in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An option with `gsubfn`.  We extract the numbers (`\\d+`) after the `-` or `,` convert it to `numeric` subtract 1 and `paste` with `-`

```
library(gsubfn)
gsubfn("[-,] ?(\\d+)",  ~ paste0("-", as.numeric(x) - 1) , as.character(abc$a))
#[1] "[100-149)" "[150-199)"
```

Comment: Wow TIL there's a whole package addressing this problem.